# A word or phrase for the following: friends who contact you only when they need something or assistance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase for the following: friends who contact you only when they need something or assistance

Comment: Can you give an example of when you would use this term? Perhaps a sentence with a blank in it?

Comment: Drinking buddies

Answer (score 2):

I thought *exploiter* was an interesting idea. So I looked at *Webster's unabridged dictionary* and came up with the following synonyms:

**Sponge, leech, gold digger, and bloodsucker.**

However I think I like *sponge* the best because of the ability to switch between noun and verb form so nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the colloquial, I'd go with

```
user
```

Let me know if that works for him.